# How to set Helvetica font?

Tags: html, css, mozilla

How to set Helvetica font?

I add css:

```
body
{
    font-family: Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: #444444;
    font-size: 9pt;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
```

but in Mozilla I see `MS shell dlg` font.

Why is this happens and how will repair it?
[image]

**Update:**

I set Arial but in Mozilla I see `MS shell dlg` again.[image]

Comment: try putting Helvetica in quotes like `font-family: "Helvetica", Sans-Serif;`

Comment: Are you sure Helvetica is installed on your system? It's an Apple-font, Arial is the Windows variant.

Comment: Yes, install, because chrome work good

Comment: How are you establishing that Chrome is using Helvetica?

Comment: @Quentin, U right chrome use `font-family: Arial;` Thanks

Comment: Is your problem solved now? Did you establih that Helvetica is indeed not installed on your system?

Comment: Yes. helvetica is not intall. My problem not solved, because mozzila not use Arial too.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want all browsers to use Arial whenever Helvetica is not available, you can always specify Arial as a second choice font.

```
body
{
    font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    color: #444444;
    font-size: 9pt;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
```

because `font-family` can use any number or arguments, and it will use the first one in the list that is available.