# CSS font family is being ignored in HTML page displayed through Linux app

Tags: html, css, linux

Im working on a HTML/CSS start page for a linux program I'm running. All my font-families were set to Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif in the css. When opening the page in Chrome or Firefox, the fonts displayed properly. Even running the windows version of the app with the same start page displayed correctly. But for whatever reason, the linux version displays the start page with all fonts replaced with courier. Its a very jarring font and I cant seem to get Linux to not default to it on this program. Ive tried changing the fonts in the css doc to Helvetica, or adding single or double quotes around each font family name, but nothing seems to change this. Does linux have some weird font quirk with css that I don't know about? any info is helpful.

Comment: I guess this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153145/css-why-is-chrome-on-linux-ignoring-my-font-family

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Google Fonts API](https://fonts.google.com/) to ensure font consistency across platforms.

Find the fonts that you are interested in on Google Fonts, if they are available. Here are the steps for how to import them into your HTML document (internet connection required):

1. Go to [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)
2. Use the search bar in the top right corner to find one of your fonts
3. Press the Plus (+) button next to your font
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for all of the fonts that you need
5. Click the *Families Selected* toolbar at the bottom of your screen
6. Select *Embed*
7. Select *Standard*
8. Copy the code block (highlighted in grey) and paste it within the `<head>` tags of your HTML document.
9. Specify the fonts that you want to use as instructed by the site (under *Specify in CSS*)